# Constant in a trace Sobolev theorem for concave domains

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, linear-pde

I wonder is the following inequality is true/known:

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a (locally) Lipschitz domain which is *the complement of a convex set*, then
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega} |u|^2 ds
\le
\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 dx + \int_{\Omega} |u|^2 dx
$$
for any $u\in H^1(\Omega)$. It is easy to prove for example for the $C^2$ case: on introduces the tubular coordinates and uses the fact that the principal curvatures of the boundary are non-positive, then the problem reduces to $\Omega=(0,\infty)$, but I do not know how to approach the Lipschitz case. Versions for more general Sobolev cases would be of interest too.